# Why are the pony engineers pulling the train in Over a Barrel?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

This is the only time they pull the train. The rest of the time they are driving the train like an engineer. Was this only a plot device for this episode or did I miss the real reason somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the answer to [your other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82354/why-is-there-such-an-odd-mix-of-technology-in-equestria) is the reason why: because that's what the plot required.

Comment: Yes. This seems very dupey indeed. The reason is "Because it's funny"; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82354/why-is-there-such-an-odd-mix-of-technology-in-equestria

Comment: They ran out of firewood or coal maybe?

Comment: The train is "found technology" and they broke it and could not figure out how to fix it?

Comment: If the ponies pull the train, that makes the engine rather redundant. As large as the rail system seems to be, they would have to have other engines on a stand by basis. I notice there is no tender with the engine. Without it, the engine wouldn't go too far. Maybe they are deadheading to where the tender is. There is at least one other train. There was a crystal looking train that stopped at the Crystal Empire.

Answer (score 2):

I dn't think there's a canon answer, but stealth might be a reasonable answer.  They're going through troubled territory at the time and might not want a loud locomotive or a trail of steam (visible, perhaps, as the moon seems to be full every night) giving away their position.

**Edit**:   maguirenumber6 pointed out that it's a crescent moon, but it's all rather bright, regardless.  Personally, I think Luna's still a little bit competitive. :)

Comment: Not wishing to be pedantic, but the Moon is only a thin crescent in the above scene, with a good deal of Earthshine illuminating the rest :-)

Comment: It all looks so bright compared to our crescent moons, I hadn't noticed. The point still stands, as it's all pretty bright, but I appreciate the correction.